# 0x80240017 error while installing microsoft visual C++ redistributable

Tags: windows-7

I'am trying to install Microsoft visual C++ redistributable x64 and getting a 0x80240017 error.

How can I resolve this?

Answer (score 1):

The error code `0x80240017` means `WU_E_NOT_APPLICABLE - Operation was not performed because there are no applicable updates`. This means the MSU can't be installed because:

- requirements to install the update are missing
- update is already installed
- update is superseded (already replaced with newer version)

Look if you ave the update [KB2999226 (Universal C Runtime)](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/2999226) already installed and remove it.